# jQuery: Wrap sibling divs of the same class with flexible selector

Tags: jquery, nextuntil

I'm looking to target all siblings of the same class name together into a container.

In this HTML,

```html
<div class="pink"></div>
<div class="pink"></div>
<div class="pink"></div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>

<div class="pink"></div>
```

I want all `.pink` divs next to each other to be wrapped in a `.pinkwrap` container, even if `.pink` doesn't have any siblings, like the last line.
All other divs are left untouched.

Ideal result:

```html
<div class="pinkwrap">
    <div class="pink"></div>
    <div class="pink"></div>
    <div class="pink"></div>
</div>

<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>

<div class="pinkwrap">
    <div class="pink"></div>
</div>
```

Here's what I've attempted in jQuery so far:

```js
var towrap = $(".pink");

towrap.each(function(){
    $(this).not(".pink + .pink").each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(":not(.pink)").addBack().wrapAll('<div class="pinkwrap">');
    });
})
```

**This works,** but if I only wanted to change the selector in my `towrap` variable without adjusting it in subsequent lines, how would I rewrite `.not(".pink + .pink")` and `.nextUntil(":not(.pink)")` to fit this?

What I've tried:

```js
var towrap = $(".pink");

towrap.each(function(){
    $(this).not(towrap + towrap).each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil().not(towrap).addBack().wrapAll('<div class="pinkwrap">');
    });
})
```

But this obviously doesn't work. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/yuzejkd7/1/) the jsfiddle.
I'm open to any suggestions and links to previous answers in case I missed any!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
The solution was to declare the div as a string, rather than a selector: `var towrap = ".pink";`

```js
var towrap = ".pink";

$(towrap).each(function(){
    $(this).not(towrap + "+" + towrap).each(function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(":not(" + towrap + ")").addBack().wrapAll('<div class="pinkwrap">');
    });
})
```

[new jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fx6zh0vw/)